# "stable identifier required" for an enumeration class

Tags: scala

In the following code segment,

```
val line = ... // a list of String array 
line match {
  case Seq("Foo", ... ) => ...
  case Seq("Bar", ... ) => ...
  ...
```

I change the above code to the followings:

```
object Title extends Enumeration  {
  type Title = Value
  val Foo, Bar, ... = Value
}

val line = ... // a list of String array 
line match {
  case Seq(Title.Foo.toString, ... ) => ...
  case Seq(Title.Bar.toString, ... ) => ...
  ...
```

And, I get an error:

```
stable identifier required, but com.abc.domain.enums.Title.Foo.toString found.
```

What will be a right way to replace a string in the case statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toString` is a function and functions cannot be used for pattern matching.

I think `Enumeration` is probably not what you are looking for.

To match a string you could

```
object Title {
  val Foo = "Foo"
  val Bar = "Bar"
}

line match {
  case Seq(Title.Foo, ...) => ???
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A function call cannot be used as a [stable identifier pattern](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html) (that is it's not a [stable identifier](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#paths)).

In particular:

> A path is one of the following.
>
> - The empty path `ε` (which cannot be written explicitly in user
>     programs).
> - `C.this`, where `C` references a class. The path this is
>     taken as a shorthand for C.this where C is the name of the class
>     directly enclosing the reference.
> - `p.x` where `p` is a path and `x` is
>     a stable member of `p`. Stable members are packages or members
>     introduced by object definitions or by value definitions of
>     non-volatile types.
> - `C.super.x` or `C.super[M].x` where `C`
>     references a class and `x` references a stable member of the super
>     class or designated parent class `M` of `C`. The prefix super is taken
>     as a shorthand for `C.super` where `C` is the name of the class
>     directly enclosing the reference.
>
> A stable identifier is a path which
>   ends in an identifier.

Thus, You cannot use a function call like `xyz.toString` in a pattern.

To make it stable you can assign it to a `val`. If the identifier starts with a lower case letter, you will need to enclose it in backticks (`) to avoid shadowing it:

```
 val line = Seq("Foo") // a list of String array
 val FooString = Title.Foo.toString
 val fooLowerCase = Title.Foo.toString

 line match {
   case Seq(FooString) => ???
   // case Seq(fooLowerCase) (no backticks) matches any sequence of 1 element, 
   // assigning it to the "fooLowerCase" identifier local to the case
   case Seq(`fooLowerCase`) => ???
 }
```

You can use guards though:

```
line match {
  case Seq(x) if x == Title.Foo.toString => ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. The approach is bit too verbose to me.

Comment: @TeeKai it's verbose but you simply cannot match on function calls. I added an example with a guard, check it out